# "jest is not defined" in NPM package

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have a small NPM package that I will use in some internal projects.
I'm adding the following mock for Jest for using it on my test scenarios:

```js
export type MockType<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: jest.Mock<unknown>;
};

export const mockQueryRunner: any = {
  connect: jest.fn(),
  startTransaction: jest.fn(),
  release: jest.fn(),
  commitTransaction: jest.fn(),
  rollbackTransaction: jest.fn(),
  manager: {
    update: jest.fn(),
  },
};

export function getDataSourceMock() {
  return {
    createQueryRunner: () => {
      return mockQueryRunner;
    },
  };
}
```

Instead of importing it locally, I'll import from my custom library.

```
import { getDataSourceMock } from '@custom/my-library';
```

However, when I try to run the project, I get the following error:

```
> nest start

ReferenceError: jest is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/my/path/@custom/my-library/get-data-source-mock.ts)
```

Why is that? No matter if I have Jest as devDependency or dependency in the library package, it is not working.

Comment: .Have you got jest installed globally
.Are you inporting jest before executing?

Comment: I have it installed globally, in the given project and in the given library. When this code is part of the project itself, it does not break. However, once I move this to the library, it starts to lack this reference.

Comment: Also, I'm executing `npm start`, which should not require Jest for execution

Comment: I would try adding an environment variables (using dotenv to import and runtime: 'import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';' and 'dotenv.config();' to the top of your file) You will then at least be able to debug.